# Layout for navigation directions

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

In my android app, I'd like to display directions similar to the example below. For now, I don't care about the icons and images or dropdown buttons, most importantly I want to display each part of the trip in a card-like layout with lists of directions.

What would the layout xml for this would look like? Is this a CardView with a RecyclerView inside of it?

[image]

Comment: It depends on the response if each time you will get the 5 objects then you can add 5 cardviews in item view of recyclerView. If its dynamic then you can user Recycler inside Recycler or LinearLayout add view programmatically.

Comment: @Sunny thanks for the reply. It would be dynamic. When you say Recycler inside Recycler, you mean the whole first `WALK/LIGHT RAIL/SUBWAY` cards are one recycler and within them they have the list of directions as another recycler?

Comment: Yes, WALK/LIGHT RAIL/SUBWAY cards are one recycler and it is the child view of the parent RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have multiple views that may repeat multiple times even contains nested items, the best way to have efficiency in runtime I think is using `RecyclerView`.